# Where can I find the possibility of a drought this summer in my area?

Tags: weather

Specifically looking to find out the likelihood  that South Carolina will experience drought conditions during the summer of 2016.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few government options here, however the National Integrated Drought Information System [drought.gov](https://www.drought.gov/) is the U.S. Drought Portal and [offers outlooks/forecasts of droughts](https://www.drought.gov/drought/data-maps-tools/outlooks-forecasts).